# CLR creates a managed heap per CPU or per Core (when in Server GC mode)?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I have managed Windows Service (serving thousands of SOAP/SignalR clients) running on production machine with quad core CPU.
It's been running a while with "Workstation GC mode". Recently I started looking towards "Server GC mode" to find out if it's a better choice for my case.
**Currently I'm stuck with this:**
For "Server GC mode" [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection) states - "A heap and a dedicated thread to perform garbage collection are provided for each CPU, and the heaps are collected at the same time".
And it's not clear whether "each CPU" means CPU or CPU Core (physical/logical). I looked into other sources and things got worse as they contradict each other.

**So my questions are:**

1. a heap and dedicated thread are created per what (CPU/CPU Core)?
2. is there a tool (a profiler) to inspect these heaps in the running managed process?

Comment: Explain what you are going to do differently when you get the answer and this might turn into a useful Q+A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. A heap is created. Actually 1 heap with 2 threads per logical core including background mode in Server gc mode.
2. Use VMMAP tool from sys internals. It shows individual heaps in detail. Other alternative would be using sos.dll with windbg.

Comment: So it's a heap per CPU or per Core?

Comment: For each logical core.